# ZF3 Is there build in debugger or how to turn on error reporting

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework3

is there a ZF3 way to turn on debugging mode? Or just to turn on printing errors on the screen? I was trying to add:

```
'debug' => true
```

to a config file but without any result. I can type:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

in the index.php, but is it a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php file of skeleton app, we find the code

```
if (array_key_exists('APPLICATION_ENV', $_SERVER) &&
 $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] === 'development') {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
}
```

So to go into development mode you have to declare an environment variable, either in your development tools, in your .htaccess file or in your vthost.
Then you can adjust your settings in `/config/development.config.php`